# How to share a link post to Facebook via the native share dialog?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift2, slcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to let users share content on **Facebook** from my app:

```
let composeSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            composeSheet.setInitialText(message)
            composeSheet.addURL(NSURL(string: shareUrl))
            composeSheet.addImage(img)
            presentViewController(composeSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works fine, but it appears as an image post, and the *link* is just appended to the message. Is it possible to make it a link post where the whole image is hyperlinked to the specified URL? Or provide some sort of a "*Call to Action*" button?

Preferably with the native dialogue...

Comment: then you go for deeplinking concept

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm referring to how the post appears on Facebook. not what what happens when you click the link.

Comment: but answer is too broad, based on your question , so mostly I added the link

Comment: prabhu would u need any help related to this